# Declaring the type of a "promisifier" function in typescript or flow

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype

I've got this function, which basically converts a (nodejs)callback-style function to a promise-style function.

```
export const promisify 
    : PromisifyT 
    = ( fn, ...args ) => {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            fn( ...args , (err, ...result) => {
                if (err) return reject(err)
                resolve(result)
            })
        }) as any
    }
```

How would i declare `PromisifyT` so that `fn`'s input types correctly map into the generated function? (Since variadic type parameters are still not supported, we could limit ourselves to a maximum of 2 or 3 parameters). Is it even possible?

PS: I've already given it a try but halted a bit when encountered problems like bad overload candidate matching.

Comment: While I write my answer, you probably do mean `as Promise<any>` at the tail end.  ...and ideally, you wouldn't even need that.

Comment: I actually dont want to worry about the type inferred in the function implementation, but i actually didnt need that cast...

Comment: Right. You were explicitly casting to any. The type is `Promise<any>` (or `Promise<{}>`). But TypeScript can happily infer that without help. It's a question of "Are you writing types for the compiler's benefit, or yours" (because the compiler may not need most of them). It would only need help if you were trying to get it to infer the return type contained within the Promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, it's just wholly not fun.

This is the type of WHOLLY NOT FUN to which I refer:

```
const resolveWith = (resolve, reject) => (err, data) =>
    err ? reject(err) : resolve(data);

type Resolver = (err:any, data:any) => void;

type Nodelike1<A> = (x:A, resolver:Resolver)=>void;
type Nodelike2<A,B> = (x:A, y:B, resolver:Resolver)=>void;
type Nodelike3<A,B,C> = (x:A, y:B, z:C, resolver:Resolver)=>void;

function promisify <A>(fn:Nodelike1<A>, x:A):Promise<any>;
function promisify <A, B>(fn:Nodelike2<A,B>, x: A, y:B):Promise<any>;
function promisify <A, B, C>(fn:Nodelike3<A,B,C>, x:A, y:B, z:C):Promise<any>;
function promisify (fn, x, y?, z?) {
  if (z != null) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      fn(x, y, z, resolveWith(resolve, reject)));
  } else if (y != null) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      fn(x, y, resolveWith(resolve, reject)));
  } else {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      fn(x, resolveWith(resolve, reject)));
  }
}

const readFile = promisify((url:string, cb) => cb(null, "Bob"), url);
```

If the `url` passed in there is a string, it will work without a hitch. If you pass in a number, TypeScript will ask if you meant something else, because from the signature of the function it was passed, it wants a string.

As you can see, you can extend that off into the sunset, and turn it into a happy 300 line long bag full of fun with generics and going backwards through the arguments list.
As a person who prefers functional programming, you can't imagine how dirty this makes me feel when I implement a compose or a curry... They are ghastly... the thought that the types are making my code safer in this case is only true if my code was written like this in the first place, rather than appeasing the compiler.

Ideally, I would take this one step further and make `promisify` return a function that expected the arguments x y and z separately from the function being passed in, so that it only looks that awkward once in the system.

But that's misery for another day.